# workbox webpack plugin workbox.precaching.prod.js loaded from wrong folder

Tags: webpack, workbox

I'm using workbox webpack plugin v3.01 with webpack v3.11.

My webpack build outputs the index.html into a wwwroot folder which is a sibling of src. The bundles go in the wwwwroot/dist folder. So, in order to cache index.html I need the service worker output to wwwroot. When deployed I don't want any references to wwwroot obviously.

**Webpack output configuration:**

```
const bundleOutputDir = "./wwwroot/dist";
...
output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
       filename: "[name].js",
       publicPath: "/dist/"
    }
```

**Workbox configuration:**

```
new workboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
                              swDest: path.join("../../wwwroot", "sw.js"),
                              clientsClaim: true,
                              skipWaiting: true,
                              importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
                              runtimeCaching: [
                                  {
                                      urlPattern: new RegExp("/api/"),
                                      handler: "networkFirst"
                                  }
                              ]
                          })
```

Everything works correctly except the plugin. In the generated sw.js I see the problem:

```html
importScripts("/dist/workbox-v3.0.1/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: "workbox-v3.0.1"});

importScripts(
  "/dist/precache-manifest.e5343547924aadc82abad909b11fc508.js"
);
```

So the workbox-sw.js file is imported from the correct location. However, the modulePathPrefix is incorrect. I believe it would work if the modulePathPrefix included /dist/.

I found a github issue which is similar (it was for manifest injection rather than GenerateSW) and it indicated a problem with the publicPath configured in the the webpack output section.

I've been experimenting with various config changes which of course are all interrelated. I wish I could somehow specify the correct modulePathPrefix.